# Drain current of NMOS circuit is constantly changing on DMM

Tags: nmos

Hello I am working on a lab that pertains to the IV characteristics of n type MOSFETS.The lab calls for recording the value of the drain current while increasing VDS/VGS from 0 to 6 volts in steps of 1 volt.

I constructed this circuit

[image]

As I increase the voltage for VDS/VGS I am experience I weird issue with the Drain Current readings. It issue is that it is not very stable at all. The current is constantly changing. I took a video of it.

https://youtu.be/-LMfpRZQWVA

is there anything I can do with the circuit to fix this?

Comment: Assuming the big jumps are when you changed the VDS voltage, it only seems to change by ~1-2% while at fixed voltage. That's not shocking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FETS have temperature coefficients for Vgs versus Ids.
Thus heating changes Vgs and causes Ids to also change.

The usual method of measuring IV characteristics uses a voltage supply for  Vgs, and a 2nd voltage supply+current meter for Ids.

To  measure at high currents (or high power), use a "pulse" test setup. Tektronix 576 curvetracers has popular.

[image]

Comment: So the increase from ~420 mA to ~482 mA in Id when increasing VGS from 5 to 6 volts is normal and the immediate drop of Id from ~482 mA to ~455 mA while VGS is at a constant 6 volts is normal?

Comment: Im picking this for the answer. The FET gets too hot to touch when VGS = 5 volts. Burned my finger tip. Thanks

Comment: For any size transistor, FET or bipolar, the heating (Id * Vce) causes changes in the IV plots. Hence machines such as TEK 576 provide a 300uS (or is it 80uS) pulsed measurement, where only the datapoint is presented. The duty-cycle drops, from 100% to 80uS/16milliSeconds (1/60Hz) or to 0.5% heating.

Answer (score 0):

\$RdsOn *I^2=Pd \$

Pd * Rja =  ΔT rise above ambient.  stabilization time takes a minute or less without forced air cooling.

Then note that MOSFETs have a positive temperature coefficient (PTC) for RdsOn.

[image]